# Concept: What is the variable names inside a child class? Do they have names?

Tags: .net, oop, class, object

I'm working with .NET but I suppose this extends to other language...

So when a child inherits a class, it gets the member variables and properties of the parent. Say there is a private variable name "mFirstName" and theres a ReadOnly property called FirstName, which gets the value of FirstName from the object.

I create another class that inherits this parent, and in the child class I can use the FirstName property to get the value of the variable in the child... but what is the name of that variable?

Or put another way, there is a private variable named mFirstName in the parent class. What do you call the equivalent variable in child class?

Comment: There is none. It's private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really a question of *name*, but one of *accessibility.*

The private field is still member state of the derived class, it just happens to be member state that you would not be able to access directly by name unless the derived class is a nested class of the base class.

```
public class Foo
{
    private int bar;

    public virtual void Do()
    {
        this.bar = 1;
    }

    private class DerivedFoo : Foo
    {
        public override void Do()
        {
            this.bar = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, the field is private but is still accessible to the derived class. An *external* class that inherits from `Foo` would not have the same ability.

So the name of the field is the same, and the field is still state of the derived class. *Accessibility* would simply entirely depend on the inheritor.

Answer (score 0):

The child class will inherit all fields, including private variables like `mFirstName`.  If the parent class implements the `FirstName` property to read and write to a private `mFirstName` variable then so will the child class unless you override it.  `mFirstName` will not be visible to the child class, however, but the `FirstName` property will - the child class must either use the parent class implementation of `FirstName` or, if allowed, implement it in some other way with an override.